# Redistributing PostgreSQL Command Line Tools

Tags: postgresql

Does anyone know if there is a  proper way to redistribute the PostgreSQL command line tools, such as pg_dump and pg_restore?

For Windows, the binaries are available in the 'One-Click' installers, but I'm only looking to redistribute the command line tools for automating backups and restores, so that > 100MB payload is completely overkill.

I could obviously just try and copy the entire bin folder, but I'd prefer knowing exactly what I need.

Comment: Are you trying to bundle some kind of rescue kit?

Comment: No, its for a line-of-business app's automatic backups feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official client-only distribution. When this question comes up on the mailing list the usual answer is that you should grab the .zip distribution then use [Dependency Walker (depends.exe)](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to determine which DLLs are required by the binaries you wish to distribute, bundle them up and include them in your app.

The PostgreSQL server (postgres.exe) uses dlopen() / LoadLibrary() very heavily so you can't rely on depends.exe for it. Thankfully the client side is simpler and you can just use depends.exe to determine what it needs. There are no additional scripts, dlopen'd libraries etc required by pg_dump, pg_restore or psql.

I've never been entirely satisfied with that answer, but I've never wanted to improve it enough to want to mess with the packaging either. It doesn't help that EnterpriseDB's one-click installer is closed source, so I can't modify it to offer a client-only minimal package. For now, extracting the executables and associated libraries is the best you're going to get.

If you think about it, it's not really that different to what'd happen if you compiled it yourself. You'd still be pulling out only the client bits to distribute.